# How to distinguish between drush and HTTP request

Tags: 7, drush

How can I distinguish whether a function is called from drush or by a real HTTP request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drush is PHP executed over the CLI (Command Line Interface), so perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/173851) can help.

Comment: In the unlikely event that cron.php was invoked over php-cli, this approach will yield a false positive.

Answer (score 8):

From drush.php:

`function_exists('drush_main')` may be used by modules to detect whether
they are being called from drush.  See http://drupal.org/node/1181308
and http://drupal.org/node/827478

Answer (score 6):

In Drupal 7:

```
if (drupal_is_cli()) {
  // Cli only code here
}
```

if you want to specifically check for drush use the above along with a check for `drush_main`.

```
if (drupal_is_cli() && function_exists('drush_main')) {}
```

In Drupal 8

```
if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli') {
  // CLI only code here
}
```

Changelog for D8: https://www.drupal.org/node/2295037

Answer (score 0):

## Request from command line

For Drupal 7, use `drupal_is_cli()`

For Drupal 5, 6 and 8, use `PHP_SAPI == 'cli'`

## Request from drush

Always use `function_exists('drush_main')`